# Cannot read property of toLowerCase of undefined error in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to set a text filter to add search functionality in my react and redux app.
When I add a text match to the title of the expense but this error is being returned in my console.

Some code that may be of help.

**Expense selector**

```
const textMatch = expense.title.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase());
```

[image: Cannot read property of toLowerCase of undefined]

Also receiving this error along with the one above:

```
react-dom.development.js:8305 The above error occurred in the <Connect(ExpSummary)> component:
```

Here is code for my expensesummary component:

```
    export const ExpSummary = ({ expCount, expTtl }) => {
    const expAlert = expCount === 1 ? 'expense' : 'expenses'; // more than 1 exp use expenses

    const formatTtlExp = numeral(expTtl / 100).format('0,0.00');
    return (
        <div className="dash-header">
            <div className="content">
                <h1 className="dash-header__title">You are viewing <span>{expCount}</span> {expAlert}, amounting to: <span>{formatTtlExp}</span></h1>
                <div className="dash-header__createexp">
                    <Link to="/create" className="btn btn--link">Create Expense</Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );

};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const visExp = selectExps(state.expenses, state.filters);

    return {
        expCount: visExp.length,
        expTtl: selectExpTtl(visExp)
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ExpSummary);
```

Been troubleshooting for last while looking for a typo but nothing!

Update**

```
Expense selector snippet
export default (expenses, { text, sortBy, startDate, endDate}) => {
    return expenses.filter((expense) => {
        const createdAtTime = moment(expense.createdAt); // get created at datetime
        const startDateMatch = startDate ? startDate.isSameOrBefore(createdAtTime, 'day') : true; // ternary op - true/false
        const endDateMatch = endDate ? endDate.isSameOrAfter(createdAtTime, 'day') : true; // ternary op - true/false
        const textMatch = expense.title.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase());

        return startDateMatch && endDateMatch && textMatch;
    }).sort((a,b) => {
        if (sortBy === 'date') {
            return a.createdAt < b.createdAt ? 1 : -1; // ascending or descending sort order
        } else if (sortBy === 'amount') {
            return a.amount < b.amount ? 1 : -1;
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: i think the error is pretty self-explanatory; `expense.title` is `undefined`; have you tried to `console.log` what the offending value is?

Comment: Yes it is - but how do I troubleshoot it myself?

Comment: Can you plase post the code snippet where the `textMatch` variable above is added.

Comment: @AndrewL added, I can add others if needed

Comment: @Napoli where should I log it from, which component?

Comment: You need to narrow down what the specific issue is and then trace back from there. In your `Expense selector snippet` if you log each `expense` in your filter function, does it have a title? I'm guessing not, since that's the error emssage, so go back a step. If you log `expenses` at the start of the function do the expense items have titles? Again I'm guessing not, so then find where you call this function and log the `expenses` argument you're passing to it. Are the titles there? Continue until you find where the error initially occurs, and analyse that.

Comment: The error you're getting is likely just the symptom of a problem that occurred some steps back. So the issue probably isn't in that snippet, you'll have to go back and find it.

Comment: @Jayce444 great troubleshooting explanation - I'm still stuck on this and I'm trying it again now. I'll get back!